# How to wait firebase, fetch data and return array in method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So i have this method in container component:

```
getProfilesOptions = () => {

    const result = firebase.firestore().collection('roles').get().then(snapshot => {
      const options = []

      snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
        options.push({ value: doc.id, label: doc.data().profile })
        //console.log(doc.id) - everything ok, i'm fetching data correctyly
      });
      return options
    })
    console.log(result)//here i have pending result in debugger
    return result
  }
```

then, i'm passing link into child...child...child component.

Then i some child i want to call it, and get array as a result, and then set the state:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    if(this.state.isFocused && !this.state.options){

      const options = this.props.getOptions()

      this.setState({
        options: options
      })
    }
  }
```

Can i have a solution of this problem? Ofcourse i can pass props as result instead of props ref to the method, but can i use the method? How to improve **getProfilesOptions?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should wrap your firebase call in a Promise, because this is an async call.

```
getProfilesOptions = () => {
   return new Promise(resolve => {
      firebase.firestore().collection('roles').get().then(snapshot => {
        const options = []

        snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
          options.push({ value: doc.id, label: doc.data().profile })
          //console.log(doc.id) - everything ok, i'm fetching data correctyly
        });
        resolve(options)
      })                                                          
   }  
}
```

And get the result in your component with .then()

```
componentDidUpdate() {
  if(this.state.isFocused && !this.state.options){

    this.props.getOptions().then(options => {
      this.setState({
        options: options
      })
    })

  }
}
```

You can read more about Javascript Promises [here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises)